# Google Maps: How to get "city" from Thai address?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps via Javascript to extract components of an address. I'm familiar with Australian addresses and that has worked well. I'm now looking to do the same for Thailand addresses (see the code below).

Here's an example address: 123/1 Sukhumvit Road, Phra Khanong Nuea, Watthana, Bangkok, Thailand

For this address (and for all other Bangkok-based ones I've tried), I can't seem to get the "Bangkok" component of the address

e.g. in the console, I get output as per the below, which have some useful components but not the 'Bangkok' part. How can I get the 'Bangkok' component of the address captured/stored into a variable?

Thanks

[image]

```
GMaps.geocode({ address: to_check, callback: function(results, status) {
  if (status=='OK') {
    for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {
        console.log(results[0].address_components[i].long_name);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Or here is some output from:                                     console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));

```
[
    {
        "address_components": [
            {
                "long_name": "1239",
                "short_name": "1239",
                "types": [
                    "street_number"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Sukhumvit Road",
                "short_name": "Sukhumvit Rd",
                "types": [
                    "route"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Khwaeng Khlong Tan Nuea",
                "short_name": "Khwaeng Khlong Tan Nuea",
                "types": [
                    "political",
                    "sublocality",
                    "sublocality_level_2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Khet Watthana",
                "short_name": "Khet Watthana",
                "types": [
                    "political",
                    "sublocality",
                    "sublocality_level_1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Krung Thep Maha Nakhon",
                "short_name": "Krung Thep Maha Nakhon",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Thailand",
                "short_name": "TH",
                "types": [
                    "country",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "10110",
                "short_name": "10110",
                "types": [
                    "postal_code"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "formatted_address": "1239 Sukhumvit Rd, Khwaeng Khlong Tan Nuea, Khet Watthana, Krung Thep Maha Nakhon 10110, Thailand",
        "geometry": {
            "location": {
                "lat": 13.7205331,
                "lng": 100.58442760000003
            },
            "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport": {
                "south": 13.7191841197085,
                "west": 100.58307861970843,
                "north": 13.7218820802915,
                "east": 100.58577658029151
            }
        },
        "place_id": "ChIJpQpSZ6Wf4jARbINdb-Lw-MM",
        "plus_code": {
            "compound_code": "PHCM+6Q Bangkok, Thailand",
            "global_code": "7P52PHCM+6Q"
        },
        "types": [
            "street_address"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4))` if you can't figure it out from that, paste that log output here.

Comment: @danh See above - can't find any field that says "Bangkok", for this address 1239 Sukhumvit Road, Khlong Tan Nuea, Watthana, Bangkok, Thailand - odd thing is that Google's Autocomplete does add in the 'Bangkok'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Krung Thep Maha Nakhon` [is Thai for "Bangkok"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangkok).  It's there in last address component before Bangkok...

```
{
    "long_name": "Krung Thep Maha Nakhon",
    "short_name": "Krung Thep Maha Nakhon",
    "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
    ]
},
```

The bias toward Thai is probably coming from the locale on the google account that setup the API key.  You can set an explicit region with "ccTLD" parameter on the request. `.us` for U.S. English. See the "Region Biasing" section in [this doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).

Comment: Although Region Biasing does take a crucial part in Place searching, it doesn't work with this case. Changing "ccTLD" doesn't work for Bangkok and Krung Thep Maha Nakhon transitions.